# TelephonyManager.allCellInfo returns all cell despite createForSubscriptionId

Tags: android, telephonymanager, cellinfo

I'm not sure if it's normal, but even though I instantiated a specific `TelephonyManager` for each of my SIM cards (with the subscriptionId), calling `allCellInfo` returns all cells detected by the device.

I use these APIs to monitor cells with `CellInfo` objects.
Our algorithm is now quite easy: a timer running every second retrieve `CellInfo` objects through 2 APIs:

- for `Android Q+`, `requestCellInfoUpdate` which works well
- for older versions, I fallback to `allCellInfo`

We used to listen to callbacks using `PhoneStateListener`, but it works erratically depending on manufacturers and devices (some Samsung devices for example).

Possible solutions:

- filter `CellInfo` on MCC/MNC: impossible as some carriers share networks. Don't know if a customer of "carrier #1" sees an antenna from "carrier #2" with MCC/MNC from "carrier #1" or "carrier #2".
- re-use `PhoneStateListener / TelephonyCallback`: `TelephonyCallback` may be working correctly, but it's only available since `Android S`. `PhoneStateListener` added a complexity to our algorithm (if it doesn't give us the right answer, then fallback to the timer). That's why we decided to remove this logic.

Does anyone have a solution to suggest to make work `allCellInfo` as intended?